# Cordova - Multiple Push Notification Services

Tags: cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com, pushwoosh

Is it possible to register multiple push notification services in one cordova application? Say I want to use both Urban Airship and Pushwoosh.

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship usually can coexist with other push providers. The library will only try to handle pushes from it's sender ID. I would recommend using 2 different gcm sender/projects, 1 for PushWoosh and 1 for Urban Airship.

Looks like PushWoosh is closed source, but after digging into the AAR it appear they are using instance IDs and the GCMPushReceiver provided by Google Play Services. That is a good sign as using the old GCM registration methods can cause conflicts with instance IDs. The only thing I am unable to verify is if PushWoosh will ignore pushes from other sender IDs or if they will try to handle Urban Airship push notifications. Most of Urban Airship's keys are prefixed with `com.urbanairship` so it will probably not be an issue even if they tried.

I think it should be fine :).